# Rails Tutorial Ch 12 exercise 1 - can't get test to fail after taking out :dependent => :destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

For Chapter 12, exercise 1, I'm having trouble figuring out why my test doesn't fail when I take out :dependent => :destroy from the User model

My test

```
@user.follow!(@followed)
@followed.destroy
@user.followers.should_not include(@followed)
```

My model, without :dependent => :destroy

```
has_many :relationships, 
  :foreign_key => "follower_id"
has_many :following, :through => :relationships, :source => :followed
has_many :reverse_relationships,
  :foreign_key => "followed_id"
  :class_name => "Relationship"
has_many :followers, :through => :reverse_relationships, :source => :follower
```

Still results in all tests passing

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an error in your testing logic....

```
  #1  @followed.destroy
  #2  @user.followers.should_not include(@followed)
```

One line #1 of your code, I think @followed becomes nil when you call destroy on it, and in line #2, there's no "nil" object in @user.followers so that's probably why your tests keep passing.  I used the following code, and it worked as expected:

```
  r1 = @user.follow!(@followed)
  r2 = @followed.follow!(@user)
  @user.destroy
  [r1, r2].each do |relationship|
    Relationship.find_by_followed_id(relationship.followed_id).should be_nil
  end
```